# MPI_Gather std::vector: 0 output at gathered vector

Tags: c++, mpi, stdvector

I would like to have the 3-loop executed by all processors (not just rank 0): each process should add what it is supposed to to sendvec and then gather it to rcvvec.

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    MPI_Init( &argc, &argv );
    int rank,size;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    int R=rank+1;
    std::vector<int> rcvvec;
    rcvvec.resize(36); // hard-coded for now: 36 = R x 2 x 2 x 3 summed over my 2 processors

    std::vector<int> sendvec;
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
    #pragma omp parallel for collapse(3) schedule(static)
    for (int n0 = 0; n0 < R; n0++) {
      for (int n1 = 0; n1 < 2; n1++) {
        for (int n2 = 0; n2 < 2; n2++) {

            for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
              #pragma omp critical
              sendvec.push_back(i);}}}}

    MPI_Gather(sendvec.data(), 1, MPI_INT, rcvvec.data(), 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);}

    if(rank==0){
      for(int i=0;i<rcvvec.size();i++)
        std::cout<<rcvvec[i]<<std::endl;
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that rcvvec is filled with zeros. I also think that sendcounts should be the size of the vector sent by every processor and rcvcounts the size of the vector received by every process, but when I replace the ones by sendvec.size(), I get a segmentation fault, which probably means I haven't understood what 'number of elements in send buffer (integer)' means.

Comment: your understanding is correct, except `sendvec.size()` has to be the same on all the ranks, and the receive buffer must be large enough `rcvec.size() >= sendvec.size() * size`

Comment: What if sendvec.size() is not the same on all ranks? Do I then have to explicitly set which part of the loop each process handles by using an if switch to assign the chunks of the loops to each task?

Comment: If the size in each rank is different, you have to use `MPI_Gatherv`.

Comment: Then `MPI_Gatherv()` is what you are looking for.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet What is the reason for rcvec.size() >= sendvec.size() * size and not strictly equal? In the above case and after following your suggestions, I had to use   rcvec.size() + 1000 such that it works properly. How can this excess space be determined? Only by trial and error or there is some mathematical reason for that?

Comment: Strictly speaking, the receive does not have to be the exact size, it only needs to be large enough. If you are still facing an issue, post a [mcve] so we discuss the same thing.